# In object-oriented world, is private keyword overused?

Tags: php, oop, private, protected

Is there any reason to use `private` keyword instead of `protected`? I can understand the purpose of it, when there is some caching property or helper method that wouldn't make sense in a child class. I see `private` in many important classes though, where I don't see the purpose of it. Here's a Symfony example: [Symfony's HttpException class](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Exception/HttpException.html):

```
namespace Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception;

class HttpException extends \RuntimeException implements HttpExceptionInterface
{
    private $statusCode;
    private $headers;

    public function __construct($statusCode, $message = null, \Exception $previous = null, array $headers = array(), $code = 0)
    {
        $this->statusCode = $statusCode;
        $this->headers = $headers;

        parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);
    }

    public function getStatusCode()
    {
        return $this->statusCode;
    }

    public function getHeaders()
    {
        return $this->headers;
    }
}
```

Is there any reason why those are not `protected`? The only one I can think of is to make programmers declare them on their own for code readability, but I'm not so sure about that. Please let me know what you think about the usage of `private` keyword here.

Comment: "Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."

Comment: In a lot of code I've seen, `private` was underused and objects were treated like records with methods.

Comment: @reaanb You are probably talking about overusing `public`, but this discussion is about `private` vs. `protected`, not `private` vs. `public`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is absolutely a reason and that reason is the Liskov substitution principle or the "L" in "SOLID" if you prefer.

The Liskov substitution principle states that if you have a type `T` and a type `S` which is a subtype of `T` then you should be able to substitute any object of type `T` with an object of type `S` without altering the correctness of your program.

`protected` members are a common method of creating violations of Liskov substitution because they allow you to overwrite behaviour found in the super type.

That's great in theory but what does it actually mean?

The *is* relationship created by inheritance is an extremely strong connection between types, far stronger than a common interface or composition because it implies implementation sharing.  A classic example of a Liskov substitution violation is the Circle-Ellipse problem, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem

This kind of problem is even more significant in the production world where other developers may end up relying upon behaviour that they think is guaranteed by the presence of a supertype but actually isn't guaranteed at all due to LSP violations - in the worst possible case, they might end up relying on incorrect behaviour such that a legitimate bug-fix in the super class creates problems elsewhere.

Whenever you make an object/method more accessible than `private` you are effectively making guarantees to other developers that, in their subtype, they can change that specific behaviour in almost any way imaginable and your code will still function correctly, so every time you make that decision, you have to ask yourself how capable you are of making that guarantee.  If you aren't confident of that then don't do it.

It is every bit as important to make sure that you don't leak implementation details of your class beyond it's boundaries via `protected` members as you would via `public` members because the pitfalls can be every bit as nasty.

This is one reason that object composition is generally preferred over inheritance.  It isn't that there is anything wrong with inheritance in principle, but the relationship between type and super type is extremely strong and it's important to make sure that that relationship is only used when it's appropriate.

---

Let's look at your example, it has a `private` status code, for example.  At the moment, that status code is effectively immutable, it's set once in the constructor and can't be mutated by any exposed method in the class.  That's good because it's an exception, we don't want it to change, we want to know about what originally caused it.

If you were were to make those members `protected`, you have no guarantee of that any longer.  A subtype of `HttpException` which represents one error at one moment, could theoretically represent a totally different error at the next.  In that situation, the class has no meaning any longer, it doesn't serve its purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is good reason especially if you write classes others will use.  By hiding the implementation and restricting access the class can be refactored without fear of breaking any users of the class.

Comment: Isn't that what is `final` keyword for, not `private`?

Comment: final on a class or method means it can't be extended or overridden.  Adding an additional protected qualifier makes callable from a subclass; private methods are not visible outside the class

Comment: a final field means it can't be changed once it's assigned